# Using phonegap-plugin-push in Chrome browser, iOS, and Android?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm missing just a single step, I can feel it...

I added the phonegap plugin to my project as so:

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --save --variable SENDER_ID="-redacted-"
```

and indeed it saved the entry into my `config.xml` file.  When I build and run the browser version

```
cordova build myApp browser
cordova run myApp browser
```

I get the error message: `Error: exec proxy not found for :: PushNotification :: init`

In the browser project folder, under `myapp\platforms\browser\platform_www\plugins` there is a `phonegap-plugin-push\www` folder with a single `push.js` file, and nothing more.  `push.js` has calls to the native plugin (eg: `exec(success, fail, 'PushNotification', 'init', [options]);`), but the plugin files that actually run the code are ... well, I don't exactly know.  That's likely the problem, don't you think?  :)

Any help getting this running in Chrome would be a big help.  I'll move on and test Android after this.

Comment: By running in Chrome, do you mean in a laptop browser?

Comment: @nyluje Yeah, Chrome browser on Windows

Comment: My guess was like the answer that has been given, it is normal it does not work. You need a device that can register to the push notification service which ever it is (GoogleCouldMsg, ApplePushNotif, and the windows one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Browser is supported now in phonegap-plugin-push have a look at [API reference](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#browser)

---

<strike>phonegap-plugin-push is **only supported in android, iOS and windows**.</strike>

you are running your app on **browser platform** which **is not supported by phonegap-plugin-push.**

you can get more information about plugin's platform support by looking it's `plugin.xml` file

for example if you look at [cordova-plugin-device's plugin.xml](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/blob/master/plugin.xml#L151). you can see browser platform at line number `151`

you'll see the following

```
<platform name="browser">
...
</platform>
```

but there is no platform proxy for browser in [phonegap-plugin-push's plugin.xml](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/plugin.xml)

Comment: Ah, see, there's my misunderstanding.  I saw "Supported for windows" and I thought that meant "browsers in a windows OS"!  Thanks for the education.

Comment: @Luth browser is supported now. added update in answer. In case you need it.